# How to instance multiple base objects in OpenGL/GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

In the classic scheme, you repeatedly draw (instance) a single object a number of times. You do this by storing the object in a VBO/IBO, storing the individual transformation matrices in another VBO, and then calling glDrawArraysInstanced/ glDrawElementsInstanced. However, I want to store multiple objects in that same VBO/IBO and in the other VBO I want to also store, along the transformation matrix, the index of the object I want to instance. Say I have 50 species of trees whose mesh data are radically different one from the other, so that I cannot create variation by simply translating/rotating/scaling one single tree specie. I must randomly instantiate from this selected range of 50 base objects, all in one DrawArrays/DrawElements call. How shall I do it?

Comment: normally? 50 drawInstanced calls, one for each type of object.

Comment: I suspect what you're after is [glMultiDrawElementsIndirect](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glMultiDrawElementsIndirect).